# which architecture is good for implementing in this project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

i am new in architecture .I have a MVC web application project and I want to use EF code FIRST  .I want to use an architecture for this project.I want to use DDD(domain driven design) but it is for large project. i want a simple of  DDD that support this things in my project:
1-repository pattern
2-IOC
3-service layer
what is your suggestion for me if anyone suggest an architecture or a sample architecture it will be  more helpful for me  thanks.

Comment: I would also have a look at CodePlanner.

Comment: thanks i check it  but i don't know  why down voting to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new MVC project and then install CodePlanner from nuget.

```
Install-Package CodePlanner
```

This will give you the architecture you are looking for.
Then follow the instructions in the readme.txt...

It will give you the chance to use DDD and will generate all code except business logic (of course).

You can see a demo of how to use it here [(11:40 into the video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hrD5MAXuIg)